# MySQL: counting null values from a query

Tags: mysql

I've a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1
```

The result is `YES | null | null | NO | null` and so more.

I would like to know how many NULL values I get, there 3. Without telling every column names, if possible.

Any tip for that?

Comment: The NULL values appear in different columns on the same row, right ?

Comment: You will need to specify every column name, but it can be done like `SELECT ((col1 IS NULL) + (col2 IS NULL) + (col3 IS NULL)...) AS num_null`

Comment: Yes Michael, I prefered a way without specify every column name, but if it's not possible, I'll make your way. Thank's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT *, ((col1 IS NULL) + (col2 IS NULL) + (col3 IS NULL)...) AS sum_null
FROM table WHERE id = 1
```